# click on back button and MediaPlayer crash Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

For MediaPlayer I have referred http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/.

I have created activity for Media Player and it is having all the functionality like play, pause, next, previous, seekbar and also includes `OnCompletionListener`. All works excellent. But now I want that all should be managed by service.

I have created MyService Class :

```
public class MusicPlayerService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    String fullStreamUrl;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            fullStreamUrl = intent.getStringExtra("fullStreamUrl");
            // Log.d("url", "Geturl:-  " + fullStreamUrl);
        }

        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(fullStreamUrl);
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mp.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

How to manage all functionality using service and currentsongIndex.
Thanks. Please clear my doubt. I am so confused.

Comment: back button crash issue are solve but next , previous , and seekbar are not working.

Comment: i have used media player code from the site which i mentioned above. in this code i am create service and try to handle all next ,previous functionality .

Comment: how you are accessing `mp` in Activity for doing `next,previous,...` operation ?

Comment: i am not accessing mp in activity . for next , previous currentSongIndex use, so how can i accessing currentSongIndex in activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manage `MediaPlayer` from Activity which is running in background using service. you should create some commands which will broadcast when `next`, `previous` , and `seekbar` action occur in Activity.

If Service is running in same process then use `LocalBroadcastManager` otherwise `BroadcastReceiver` for getting events from Activity.

For example:

**1.** Create Actions for next,previous,... operations in Service:

```
  public static String STR_NEXT="MusicPlayerService.NEXT";
  public static String STR_PREV="MusicPlayerService.PREV";
```

**2.** Register receiver with all Action in  `onCreate` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  mp = new MediaPlayer();
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction(STR_NEXT);
  filter.addAction(STR_PREV);   
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).
           registerReceiver(mediaAction,filter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mediaAction = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(intent.getAction().equals(STR_NEXT)){
              forwardClick();
            }
           // do same for other actions
        }
};
```

**3.** Create a method in Service for next operation:

```
public void forwardClick(){
  int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
  if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
   mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
  }else{ 
   mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
  }
}
```

create other methods in same way.

**4.** From Activity on Button click send broadcast with required Action:

```
btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MusicPlayerService.STR_NEXT);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(
                       view.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
 });
```

send broadcast in same way for other actions.

Comment: Thanks its work  but how can i manage  pause, next, seekBar,  i mean next button code i write in service then how can i change image. and also display seekbarprogress...

Comment: @Priyank: In same way as you are sending events from Activity to Service. do same for sending event for changing images, seekbar progress from Service to Activity

Answer (score 0):

On onDestroy() try

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: back button my media player is working , and song is play but how to manage next , previous, Forward , and seekBarProgress ..

Comment: Try BroadcastReceiver. It may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try going through your logcat messages or paste them here for us to be able to trace the error.